# (WindowsPrincipal vs GenericPrincipal vs ClaimsPrincipal)'s Identity property

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-identity, wif, claims-based-identity

TL;DR.  I'm writing this up to potentially help someone else's googling in the future as I found no documentation on this particular behaviour, and partly on the hope that someone could confirm (or deny) that this is the *correct* approach (in summary use .Identities.First() not .Identity!)
...
So, my team has some code that manipulates 'claims' (a claims transformation if you will) that looks something like:

```
var claimsIdentity = ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Authentication.User.Identity);
var transformedClaims = await this.Transformer.Transform(dbContext, claimsIdentity.Claims);
foreach (var claim in claimsIdentity.Claims.ToList())
{
    claimsIdentity.RemoveClaim(claim);
}
claimsIdentity.AddClaims(transformedClaims);
```

And later some code that 'checks' for these claims, which looks like:

```
((ClaimsPrincipal)context.Authentication.User).HasClaim(permission.ClaimType, permission.ClaimValue);
```

This code has been working absolutely fine, until some bright spark (me) noticed that our web.config was missing an `<authentication mode="None">` element.  However as soon as I put this in the authentication logic went to hell (specifically the 'HasClaim' call no longer returned true.)

We eventually traced the fault to the type of Principal changing from a `WindowsPrincipal` instance to a `GenericPrincipal`. *Specifically* reading through the sourcecode I can see that when a GenericPrincipal is passed an `Identity` in the constructor a *clone* of this is used as an entry in the Identities property of the `context.Authentication.User` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/principal/genericprincipal.cs#L98).

The 'HasClaim' method then iterates over the Identities collection, but ignores the single 'Identity' property so our code is manipulating (in the case of `GenericPrincipal`) the *wrong* instance of Identity's claims.

Sooooo with this in mind I've had a looksy around the internet and I've noticed that when anyone else manipulates claims I see code such as:
     var id = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();
or
    ClaimsIdentity aspNetIdentity = principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault(...)

This would happen to work for all; `GenericPrincipal`, `WindowsPrincipal` and `ClaimsPrincipal` instances (the latter two because the first instance of the `Identities` is usually the same as the `Identity` property and the first because the 'HasClaim' method queries this same collection.)

Did I miss the memo where it says we need to do this (I can't see any comments to this end on the API docs from Microsoft)?